Posts to Article in Wordpress - getting undefined array key 0
I'm using the following code to change POSTS to ARTICLES within the admin of Wordpress.  (I got this from this 2012 thread Change label Posts to Articles in Wordpress ... and was sourced from https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9211/changing-admin-menu-labels)
// Function to change "posts" to "Articles" in the admin side menu
function change_post_menu_label() {
    global $menu;
    global $submenu;
    $menu[5][0] = 'Articles';
    $submenu['edit.php'][5][0] = 'Articles';
    $submenu['edit.php'][10][0] = 'Add Article';
    $submenu['edit.php'][16][0] = 'Tags';
    echo '';
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'change_post_menu_label' );
// Function to change post object labels to "news"
function change_post_object_label() {
    global $wp_post_types;
    $labels = &$wp_post_types['post']->labels;
    $labels->name = 'Articles';
    $labels->singular_name = 'Article';
    $labels->add_new = 'Add Article';
    $labels->add_new_item = 'Add Article';
    $labels->edit_item = 'Edit Article';
    $labels->new_item = 'Article';
    $labels->view_item = 'View Article';
    /* error reporting lines start here */
    $labels->search_items = 'Search Articles';
    $labels->not_found = 'No Articles found';
    $labels->not_found_in_trash = 'No Articles found in Trash';
}
/* error reporting lines end here */
add_action( 'init', 'change_post_object_label' );

But, there is an error log in my wp-admin folder that has several "PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 0 in" ... and it starts around the last few line ($labels->search_items = ...), and the lines after that.  I don't think those array keys have been deprecated and are no longer used in WordPress (but, if they were, wouldn't that give a different error?).
I've check threads on Stackoverflow for this (i.e. PHP Warning: Undefined array key 0 in ) ... Its certainly not an empty array (no error for the lines above $labels->search_items), and the I'm not getting errors above those lines. Also... should it matter that array key 0 is missing (since I'm calling out specific array keys)?
Since this is in my functions.php file, I don't want to start messing with the code too much and blowing up my site.
Can anyone tell me what is wrong, and how to fix it?

The code, however awful, works for me on a vanilla install of WordPress 6.6.1.
It is possible, however, that various plugins and themes will mess with the menu and submenu orders, which is probably why you get index warnings.
The hook you should actually be using to change post type labels is post_type_labels_{$post_type}.
The following code should get you started:
add_filter( 'post_type_labels_post', function( $labels ) {
    foreach ( ( array )$labels as $key => $value ) {
        $labels->$key = str_replace( 'Post', 'Article', $value ?? '' );
    }

    // Can also be set individually as per your code, but it misses a lot.

    return $labels;
}, 10, 1 );


It replaces all the "Post" words in all labels to "Article". You've missed a lot of label keys that appear in WordPress 6.6.1:
{
    "name": "Articles",
    "singular_name": "Article",
    "add_new": "Add Article",
    "add_new_item": "Add Article",
    "edit_item": "Edit Article",
    "new_item": "Article",
    "view_item": "View Article",
    "view_items": "View Posts",
    "search_items": "Search Articles",
    "not_found": "No Articles found",
    "not_found_in_trash": "No Articles found in Trash",
    "parent_item_colon": null,
    "all_items": "All Posts",
    "archives": "Post Archives",
    "attributes": "Post Attributes",
    "insert_into_item": "Insert into post",
    "uploaded_to_this_item": "Uploaded to this post",
    "featured_image": "Featured image",
    "set_featured_image": "Set featured image",
    "remove_featured_image": "Remove featured image",
    "use_featured_image": "Use as featured image",
    "filter_items_list": "Filter posts list",
    "filter_by_date": "Filter by date",
    "items_list_navigation": "Posts list navigation",
    "items_list": "Posts list",
    "item_published": "Post published.",
    "item_published_privately": "Post published privately.",
    "item_reverted_to_draft": "Post reverted to draft.",
    "item_trashed": "Post trashed.",
    "item_scheduled": "Post scheduled.",
    "item_updated": "Post updated.",
    "item_link": "Post Link",
    "item_link_description": "A link to a post.",
    "menu_name": "Posts",
    "name_admin_bar": "Post"
}


So, should I replace that where ... $labels->name ... starts down to ... $labels->not_found_in_trash = 'No Articles found in Trash'; ... with the add_filter() function that you provided? It looks like there's extra numbers and a bracket at the end... Note: My knowledge of PHP and WordPress are pretty limited (just trying to avoid causing the site not to crash.

@user3412194 remove everything you have in your question with the add_filter() provided here. The extra numbers mean: load order (10), arguments passed to the function you are filtering (1). You can technically remove those since they are the default values expected by this particular function filter.

So, I replaced the items...  and it appears to be working (and I don't see the errors in the logs). Quick questions though ... I am using Adobe Dreamweaver to edit the functions.php. On the 3rd line of the new code, it says "syntax error, unexpeceted '?'" ... Not sure if the two ?? are giving the error, or why. Just curious why its happening and if I should be worried...

@user3412194 looks like Dreamweaver doesn't support the ?? operator that appeared in newer versions of PHP. You can replace the whole line with: if ($value) $labels->$key = str_replace( 'Post', 'Article', $value ); as an alternative syntax that's compatible with older versions of PHP. Glad to hear this helped. Please don't forget to mark the answer as the solution. Thank you!
